# Store Live CD's on HD and Boot from GRUB

Tags: linux, boot, grub, imaging, clonezilla

I use **"Clonezilla"**  and the **"SystemRescueCD"** on a lot of servers and I was wondering if there' s a way to copy the ISO files (from the above tools) into a partition (e.g in every server) and modify grub.conf accordingly so that I could reboot the server and boot from these.

With this, I won't have to have to deal with CD media whenever I want to clone the servers and I could do the cloning much faster as the above tools are going to be booting from a faster device.

Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks,
JFA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about directly booting to an ISO, but installing SystemRescueCD to a hard drive and booting off it is pretty easy.  I suspec this may also be true for Clonezilla, and many other livecds

- Pop a SystemRescueCD CD into your drive and mount it.
- Copy the contents of the drive to a folder

  - rsync -a /media/cdrom0/ /boot/sysrcd/
- Update your grub configuration and configury an entry to boot the SystemRescueCD image from /boot/sysrcd/

```
    title     SystemRescueCD + docache,dodhcp
    # paths assume /boot is on a seperate partition.
    kernel    /sysrcd/isolinux/rescuecd subdir=sysrcd initrd=/sysrcd/isolinux/initram.igz setkmap=us setkmap=us scandelay=5 docache
    quiet
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your suggestion initially but couldn't make it to work but then I found this URL:  http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Easy_install_SystemRescueCd_on_harddisk that has it all.